# NPM package install into public directory (best practice)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, public

Currently I am working on a website project. Its file structure looks like below:

```
source_code
- application
- node_modules
- system
- www
-- js
-- css
-- img
-- third-party
-- index.php
- package.json
```

This time I would like to ensure third-party libraries with NPM.

What is the best practice if some package should be available in public way and I want to avoid the manual copy-paste flow.
(Example packages: jquery, lazysize, bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're setting things up to be used. If you're using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), for example, you would probably handle your JavaScript dependencies in `package.json`, and let webpack collect all these into a `dist/bundle.js` file which is the actual JS file included in your `index.html`.

If you don't have a packaging step like this set up, you can do one of these methods:

- Link out to a CDN in your index.html (`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>`)
- Download this file in `www/js/lib/` and include it locally within the site (`<script src="/js/lib/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>`).